# replace if condition by match

Tags: rust, match

I am trying to improve my use of `match` expression.

I have a code like the following where `foo` is a String:

```rust
if foo.chars().nth(0).unwrap() != '2' && 
    foo.chars().nth(0).unwrap() != '3' &&
    &foo[0..3] != "xyz"
    {
        return message;
    }
```

Is it possible to create the same behavior using match?
Something like this idea:

```rust
match foo {
   &[0] == (2 | 3) => do_nothing
   &[0..3] == "xyz" => do_nothing
   _ => return message;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach:

1. The matched expression must be unique. You can't match `foo[0]` in some branches and `foo[0..3]` in some other branches. So let's pick the biggest range: `foo[0..3]`.
2. Rust string matching cannot match sub-strings: it's all or nothing. Slices don't have that limitation and we can freely get a slice of bytes, so let's match `&foo.as_bytes()[0..3]`.

```
match &foo.as_bytes()[0..3] {
    &[b'2', ..] | &[b'3', ..] => do_nothing(),
    b"xyz" => do_nothing(),
    _ => return message,
}
```

There is a [proposal to make `|` a regular pattern](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54883) rather than a special construct of `match`, which would make the first branch expressable as `&[2 | 3, ..]`